# How to update List Class Data if Data Exits

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have Created a List class where i will add some data. My requirement is if data exits it will update data, If not then it will add Data. I have tried some code but its give a error.

```
public class Subject
{
    public string m_SubjectId { get; set; }
    public double m_Marks { get; set; }
    public double m_NegativeMarks { get; set; }
    public double m_TotalMarks { get; set; }


    public void AddSubjectDeatils(string SubjectId, double Marks, double NegativeMark)
    {
        List<Subject> lst = new List<Subject>();
        var temp = lst.Single(l => l.m_SubjectId == SubjectId);
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp.m_Marks += Marks;
            temp.m_NegativeMarks += NegativeMark;
            temp.m_TotalMarks += Marks;                
        }
        else
        {
            m_SubjectId = SubjectId;
            m_Marks = Marks;
            m_NegativeMarks = NegativeMark;
            m_TotalMarks = Marks;                
        }
    }
}
```

The Error Is : Sequence contains no matching element

Comment: Use `Find` method instead of `Single`

Comment: You do realize that you're creating a new, empty `List<T>` (`lst`) every time you call your method, right?  `List<Subject> lst = new List<Subject>();`.  You'll never find a match in this situation.

Comment: @Tim got u. Thanks.Tim please correct the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var temp = lst.Single(l => l.m_SubjectId == SubjectId);
```

use `SingleOrDefault` instead (or `FirstOrDefault` should be enough), if you want one or no result.

With `Single`,

```
if (temp != null)... else
```

doesn't make sense, because an `Exception` will be raised before accessing this test if you have no result.

By the way, `lst` should be a parameter of your method, or the return value of a call to another method.

As it is :

```
List<Subject> lst = new List<Subject>();
var temp = lst.Single(l => l.m_SubjectId == SubjectId);
```

You will never get anything inside (you create an empty list on each call to your method)

Comment: You are right. Error is not Coming now. But i getting empty data, Then how do i correct it ?

Comment: @Raghubar well, as mentioned : lst could be a parameter of your method, or it should be the result of another method...

Answer (score 1):

You're creating new `List<Subject>` every time the method is called. I think it's not correct.

You should also use `SingleOrDefault` instead of `Single` to prevent it from throwing exception.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the List in your Main method and pass it as an argument to the AddSubjectDetails function

```
public void AddSubjectDeatils(string SubjectId, double Marks, double NegativeMark,List<Subject> listofsubjects)
    {

        var temp = listofsubjects.SingleorDefault(l => l.m_SubjectId == SubjectId);
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp.m_Marks += Marks;
            temp.m_NegativeMarks += NegativeMark;
            temp.m_TotalMarks += Marks;
        }
        else
        {
            m_SubjectId = SubjectId;
            m_Marks = Marks;
            m_NegativeMarks = NegativeMark;
            m_TotalMarks = Marks;
        }
    }
```